# How to Revoke Token generated on Azure AD On Behalf user flow?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I am getting access token and then calling MS graph API , however i am not getting any API for revoking the access token /refresh token generated for specific account(used on behalf of user authorization flow).

Used the azure AD logout API which redirects to the logout URL but not exactly logging out of Office 365 account and can still able to generate the new access token using refresh token after logout. This should not happen.

Please suggest some solution.

Comment: The refresh tokens are meant to be used by apps for offline access to data, allowing background synchronization operations etc. So a log out should not invalidate refresh tokens in general. What is your scenario? Usually refresh tokens are only manually invalidated if you think the account has been hacked.

Comment: Hi Juunas, Our  web app project requirement is to add the office 365 account and use it to send mail and show inbox into the webapp. There is also the requirement that we can remove the office 365 account and add different mail account into the web app . at a time user should add his office account or gmail account so in that case to remove the office account i need a solution , have searched for the API accordingly but dint find anything related to this scenario

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your only option is here cmdlet Revoke-AzureADUserAllRefreshToken.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/revoke-azureaduserallrefreshtoken?view=azureadps-2.0

Your case is also described in the Office 365 scope over here: https://www.michev.info/Blog/Post/1137/immediately-revoke-access-to-office-365-applications

Comment: Hi Luke thanks for the response. but as Juunas mentioned in above comment about revoking the refresh token is used in case of account gets hacked and want to stop unauthorized access so this revoking refresh does not seems good idea for removing the Office 365 account from my web application.

Comment: In case of hack scenario/trying unauthorized access then you need to consider looking at the CAE https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/concept-fundamentals-continuous-access-evaluation and see if it helps.